# Is there a way to use inline r in YAML refernce_docx when knitting to Word?

Tags: r, knitr

Using knitr to create Word documents from Rmarkdown files I have had no trouble using the YAML 'reference_docx' argument specifying a relative path, and have successfully use inline R in the 'date' argument, but I get an error if I try to use inline R in the reference_docx argument. I want to incorporate my reference document into the /inst folder in a personal package so that if I make any changes to the template all of my projects can be easily updated.

This works:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "My name"
date: '`r lubridate::today()`'
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "../Styles/Reference_Document.docx"
---
```

But this does not:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "My name"
date: '`r lubridate::today()`'
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: '`r system.file("Styles", "Reference_Document.docx", package = "mypackage")`'
---
```

I also tried using `file.path(.libPaths[1], "mypackage", "Styles", "Reference_Document.docx")` with no luck. I know the file exists because if I write out the full path then the knit will go fine.

Here is the error I get using the above example:

```
pandoc.exe: `r system.file("Styles", "Reference_Document.docx", package = "mypackage")`: openBinaryFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument)
```

Am I just running into a problem with how certain YAML arguments are passed to pandoc? And is there a workaround to use your own reference documents or templates in a package?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but essentially the same question, so the answer will be very similar.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it @Yihui

Comment: So apparently the way to do this is: `reference_docx: !expr system.file("Styles", "Reference_Document.docx", package = "mypackage")`